# Adding PDFKit Palette in XCode 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am a new iOS developer learning Objective-C. I am currently using XCode 9. I am trying to use PDFKit to work in my app, and I am following these links for tutorials:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Tasks/PDFKit_Prog_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001863-CH202-CHDIADBJ (From the official Apple developer site)

http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/cocoa/pdfkit.html

For both tutorials, they tell me I should add the PDFKit.Palette from my Interface Builder. The problem is, I think the Interface Builder in XCode 9 looks rather different than from previous XCode versions. I tried finding "Preferences" when I open the Interface Builder, but I can't see that option nor the "Palettes" tab.

I have added PDFKit.Framework and Quartz.Framework in my project, and I have access to files such as PDFView.h and PDFKit.h. Do I still have to add the PDFKit palette? If so, could anyone offer insight as to how I could add the palette via my Interface Builder? I have searched for many solutions online, but most of them are rather outdated.

Thank you in advance, and I apologize if my question sounds all over the place. I am really confused about this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure those docs are really old. This question was asked a while ago, so hopefully this helps someone else.

I'm using swift, so your code will be slightly different to mine.

I couldn't see PDFView in interface builder either. The way I got around it was to just add an empty UIView in interface builder and gave it the PDFView class.

Then in the view controller I added:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!
```

then dragged the little dot to the view in interface builder

and in viewDidLoad I added (where url is the file url of my pdf document):

```
let pdf = PDFDocument(url: url!)
pdfView.document = pdf
```